# working with empty data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to define an empty df outside a `for loop` and then fill the rows/columns from inside the loop, something like this:

```
df<- data.frame()
    for (fl in files){
      dt <- read.table(fl, header = FALSE, col.names = c("year","month","value"),
       colClasses = c("character","character","numeric"))
      t <- aggregate(value ~ year, dt, sum)
      df$year <- t$year
      df$value <- t$value * someFunction() 
    }
```

Now, There are a various ways to create an empty df in R.

```
df <- data.frame()

# or another method
df <- data.frame(Month=character(), 
                 Value=character(), 
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 

# or another method
df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 2))
```

But when I assign values to the data frame, the following error is produced:

```
df$Month <- month.abb

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, File, value = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar",  : 
  replacement has 12 rows, data has 0
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong or any misconception that I might have, but I couldn't find my way around this. Can anyone explain it to me ?

P.S: `df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 100, ncol = 2))` works but I don't know if its a good idea because my df will have different number of rows.

Comment: Can you show the broader aspect of what you're trying to achieve? There is bound to be a more appropriate way of doing things.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik question edited

Comment: in your loop you're overwriting the df at each iteration

Comment: yes, I will deal with it later on, for now I just need to figure out a way to fill in data without getting the error as i mentioned. @Moody_Mudskipper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 4 ways to grow your `data.frame`:

```
col1 <- letters[1:3] # [1] "a" "b" "c"
col2 <- letters[4:6] # [1] "d" "e" "f"
```

1- Start by assigning the first column

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df1$col2 <- col2
```

2- Grow a list first, convert afterwards

```
l2 <- list()
l2$col1 <- col1
l2$col2 <- col2
df2 <- data.frame(l2,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

3- Define the data.frame with columns initiated with the right length:

```
df3 <- data.frame(col1 = character(3), col2 = character(3))
df3$col1 <- col1
df3$col2 <- col2
```

4- Set rownames when you define it so it has 0 column and n rows

```
df4 <- data.frame(row.names = 1:3)
df4$col1 <- col1
df4$col2 <- col2
```

Check that it's all equivalent:

```
identical(df1,df2) # [1] TRUE
identical(df1,df3) # [1] TRUE
identical(df1,df4) # [1] TRUE
```

Comment: It looks like this solves it. BTW 3 and 4 sets the number of rows at the beginning, which will actually be uncertain since I have to read from file and different files have different number of rows. Say I set row numbers to 100 and the file has only 20 rows then will the df have 5 copies of the data or only 20 rows ?

Comment: I believe it might be a XY problem. Maybe you should subset `t` (that you shouldn't name `t` as it's also the transpose function ) or a copy of it rather than copying columns from t to df.

Comment: Assigning to a df with the wrong number of rows will trigger an error, it won't recycle, if it's your question

Comment: yeah, I meant if it would repeat itself. If it does not repeat then all of your 4 options would be great.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the values to a list in the for loop, and then you can bind the rows together as a data frame. Something like this:

```
myList <- list()

for (m in 1:length(month.abb)) {
  myList[[m]] <- month.abb[m]

}

df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, myList))
```

Comment: no!  actually I need to read data from a lot of files and then operate on them.

Comment: @anup no what? This approach is easily adjusted to solve your specific problem

Comment: I really appreciate your effort but rbind approach would work if i am building rows inside the loop just like you did. But I have to read data from a table into a df, perform some calculations, and then store it to another df. Moody's answer is something more suitable for my case. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

If one needs to execute the same set of calculations on a number of input files, one can accomplish this with an `apply()` function, avoiding the need for a `for()` loop.

To illustrate, we'll use the data from Alberto Barradas' [Pokémon with stats](https://www.kaggle.com/abcsds/pokemon) database that he posted to Kaggle. The actual CSV files I used are accessible on my [PokémonData github repository](https://github.com/lgreski/pokemonData).

I split the data into 6 separate CSV files, one per generation of Pokémon. To make the example completely reproducible, the files are downloaded then stored in a subdirectory of the R Working Directory.

We'll read the file names with `list.files()` so we can process a variable number of files without having to hand edit the file names, and use the result as input into `lapply()`. We'll also use an anonymous function to read the data and perform additional calculations.

The output from `lapply()` is a list of dataframes that can be subsequently processed individually, or combined into a single data frame with `do.call()` as illustrated in one of the other answers.

```
download.file("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lgreski/pokemonData/master/pokemonData.zip",
              "pokemonData.zip",
              method="curl",mode="wb")
unzip("pokemonData.zip")

thePokemonFiles <- list.files("./pokemonData",
                              full.names=TRUE)    
pokemonDataFiles <- lapply(thePokemonFiles,function(x) {
     y <- read.csv(x,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
     y$speedSquared <- y$Speed^2
     y # return data frame to result object
     })
head(pokemonDataFiles[[1]])
```

...and the output:

```
> head(pokemonDataFiles[[1]])
  Number                  Name Type1  Type2 Total HP Attack Defense SpecialAtk SpecialDef Speed Generation Legendary
1      1             Bulbasaur Grass Poison   318 45     49      49         65         65    45          1     False
2      2               Ivysaur Grass Poison   405 60     62      63         80         80    60          1     False
3      3              Venusaur Grass Poison   525 80     82      83        100        100    80          1     False
4      3 VenusaurMega Venusaur Grass Poison   625 80    100     123        122        120    80          1     False
5      4            Charmander  Fire          309 39     52      43         60         50    65          1     False
6      5            Charmeleon  Fire          405 58     64      58         80         65    80          1     False
  speedSquared
1         2025
2         3600
3         6400
4         6400
5         4225
6         6400
>
```

DISCLOSURE: this code is based on code I published in a blog article during 2017, [Forms of the Extract Operator](https://github.com/lgreski/datasciencectacontent/blob/master/markdown/rprog-extractOperator.md).

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
months = c("Jan","Feb","Mar")

df <- data.frame(Month=character(), 
             Value=character(), 
             stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

for (i in 1:length(months)){

    df[i,1] = months[i]
}
```